# How to store a specified number of sequences of integers in an ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to store a specified number of sequences of integers in an ArrayList.

The number of sequences is going to be defined by the user.

For example, if the user enters 3 then the program will know that there will be 3 sequences inserted.

Each sequence ends when a 0 is inserted. For example, the next user input could be:
    1 2 3 0
    4 5 6 7 8 0
    11 12 0

I want to store these sequences and then do some calculations on each of them. How do I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("number of sequences: ");
    int size = scan.nextInt();
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //How to get the input sequences by sequence?


    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: How do you do what, exactly?  You haven't shown us what you've done so far, nor mentioned what part you're stuck on.  Are you having a problem reading user input?  Do you not understand how to parse input into numbers?  Do you need to know how lists work?

Comment: public static void main (String[] args){
          Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
          System.out.println("data in: ");
          int size = scan.nextInt();
          List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  
          //STUCK HERE - HOW TO STORE THE NUMBERS IN                           "arr"?
          scan.close();
         }

Comment: Please don't try to dump code into a comment.  You need to edit your question to add it there.  Code in comments is unformatted and unreadable.

Comment: OK, just edited the question!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ArrayLists, you can use a generic type:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

You can fill this list with ArrayList of Integers. 
You can make this new ArrayList of Integers with a for loop, which exits the loop when the given numbers of lists.
For example:

```
for (int i=0; i < userInputNumber; i++) { 
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // fill the newList object with the user input list of integers
    myList.add(newList)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's some semi-pseudo code to help get you started

```
//beginning number
int numOfSequences = readUserInputAsInt()

//make an array big enough to hold all the sequences
List<Integer>[] sequences = new List<Integer>[numOfSequences];

// read all the next input as one big string
String userInput = readUserInputAsString();

//this method would split the userInput string up by spaces to get each integer
int[] numbers = convertStringToIntArray(userInput);

//put each number in to the correct sequence list
int sequenceNumber = 0;
for(int number : numbers) {
    // if we haven't used this sequence before, create a new list to hold it
    if(sequences[sequenceNumber] == null){
        sequences[sequenceNumber] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    //  if number is 0, end that sequence, else add the number to the sequence
    if(number == 0) {
        sequenceNumber++;
    } else {
        sequences[sequenceNumber].add(number);
    }
}

// do work on 'sequences'
```